# SHA256 mismatch for hd5view brew install

Tags: homebrew, sha256, hdf

I am trying to install hdfview but running into an issue where the download is getting interrupted. I'm being asked to remove this file (which I tried removing) but keep getting the same error. I have already downloaded hdf5 and also uninstalled and reinstalled brew, also updated it and ran clean up and doctor as well (which told me to update Xcode and I did).

```
Error: SHA256 mismatch
Expected: 91ee9832cd8a82e6d127faf5dc1b156523ecf995a552e08a07ebe37c45bf17da
  Actual: f311c4bc740e1a1935c5d02a4dfb2375177ac36d16bb872aecf7e2c3c0643db9
    File: /Users/mahesh/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/6591cb809eb4d382b81e7d42924fe1219528a81eef40a2b3455d113ca2c878e4--HDFView-3.3.1-macos11_64.tar.gz
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

I tried removing the file and then double checked that that file was removed

```
mahesh@Pranjals-MacBook ~ % rm /Users/mahesh/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/6591cb809eb4d382b81e7d42924fe1219528a81eef40a2b3455d113ca2c878e4--HDFView-3.3.1-macos11_64.tar.gz
mahesh@Pranjals-MacBook ~ % rm /Users/mahesh/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/6591cb809eb4d382b81e7d42924fe1219528a81eef40a2b3455d113ca2c878e4--HDFView-3.3.1-macos11_64.tar.gz
rm: /Users/mahesh/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/6591cb809eb4d382b81e7d42924fe1219528a81eef40a2b3455d113ca2c878e4--HDFView-3.3.1-macos11_64.tar.gz: No such file or directory
mahesh@Pranjals-MacBook ~ % brew install --cask hdfview
==> Downloading https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/releases/HDF-JAVA/hdfview-
######################################################################### 100.0%
Error: SHA256 mismatch
Expected: 91ee9832cd8a82e6d127faf5dc1b156523ecf995a552e08a07ebe37c45bf17da
  Actual: f311c4bc740e1a1935c5d02a4dfb2375177ac36d16bb872aecf7e2c3c0643db9
    File: /Users/mahesh/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/6591cb809eb4d382b81e7d42924fe1219528a81eef40a2b3455d113ca2c878e4--HDFView-3.3.1-macos11_64.tar.gz
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

I am not super familiar with working in the terminal and not sure if I'm just doing something wrong? I would appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm running into the same situation and doing a `brew edit hdfview` to change the `sha256` hash to the one given or commenting it out entirely both do not let the install proceed.  Hopefully someone has a solution for this...